# custom UITableView header similar to UISearchBar

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, scroll

I want to put my custom header view to UITableView with automatic scroll offset adjustments which UISearchBar have.

How I can do this?

Comment: Please post the specific problem you're having in implementing this.

Comment: There is no problem in adding custom header view to UITableView. Problem is that the behavior of table view scrolling is different when using UISearchBar as a header. I want to keep this behavior on my custom view.

Comment: I've found the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826810/uitableview-with-header-works-incorrectly-for-any-view-except-uisearchbar?answertab=active#tab-top . But there is no answer too

Answer (score 2):

Found workaround. I add my header to UISerachBar as subview and hide all other subviews of search bar

```
-(void)addHeaderView:(UIView *)view
{
    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:view.frame];
    [searchBar layoutSubviews];

    UIView *searchBarView = searchBar.subviews[0];

    for (UIView *subview in searchBarView.subviews)
        subview.hidden = YES;

    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [searchBarView addSubview:view];
    self.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
}
```