# TableView Header like iOS 7 Mail and Messages App

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uiscrollview

**EDIT: I think I am narrowing down the issue here. I just found an easier way to recreate what I want. If you create a new project with a storyboard, drag on a tableview controller and drag on a Search Bar as a subview of the tableview. If you run this (with some dummy cells), and you scroll so about half of the search bar is showing, the search bar will snap to the top of the view. If you try this by dragging on a UIView instead of a Search Bar, this behavior no longer happens. How can I get this behavior with a UIView as a subview?**

Hopefully this made it more clear, thanks guys.

I have a header in my plain style table view, I am implementing it like this:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return 51;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    SegmentedHeaderView *header = [[SegmentedHeaderView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 51)];

    return header;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat sectionHeaderHeight = 51;
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<=sectionHeaderHeight&&scrollView.contentOffset.y>=0) {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0, 0, 0);
    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y>=sectionHeaderHeight) {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-sectionHeaderHeight, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

I want the header to scroll with the tableview and not stick to the top, and it does that correctly. However, when I scroll to the top, I want the header to work like the search bar header does in the messages app in iOS 7. In the messages app, when you are scrolling and you stop halfway through the search bar, either the search bar sticks to the top of the view, or the first cell sticks to the top of the view.

How can I implement this so when the user stops scrolling with part of the header view showing the header jumps up?

Edit: The behavior I want can also be seen with the search bar in the Mail app.

Comment: What's off about your approach? It seems like a good solution to me.

Comment: Well that does make the header scroll with the table view, but if I stop scrolling with only part of the header showing, it stays like that instead of the header jumping and sticking to the top like in messages.

Comment: Anyone think they can help?

Comment: This solved the problem for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24380111/2584268
Turns out you can only get that behavior with a search bar.